# URL for localhost website's video files

Tags: java, android, asp.net, networking, localhost

I'm trying to develop an Android app that can access a website's video files and download them. My code works well with public websites but I'm trying to figure out the url I could use for a website on my localhost.

My friend developed a simple site which I can upload video files. The videos are uploaded to the projects ".Web\Assets\Videos" directory. But I'm having trouble determining the url for the localhosted video files.

http://192.168.1.23:11124/Assets/Videos/video1.mp4

file:///192.168.1.23:11124/Assets/Videos/video1.mp4

Both dont seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: if its an app that downloads videos from usual websites, you have to use http. if you use http you have to setup a http server on the device you want to download the video from. you could try using something like xampp to run an apache server on your device and place the video files in xampps htdocs folder.

Comment: The way you're writing it it looks like with localhost you mean another machine in your LAN other than your Android device. If so, you need to make sure that that machine's firewall is not blocking this port. Can you access the files through your webbrowser on your android? And what about on what you call localhost? Try using localhost:11124 or 127.0.0.1 instead of the IP address if you are in fact talking about your Android device.

Comment: using localhost gives me ECONNREFUSED error. i might be using the wrong url though.                                                                                        "C:\Users\efe\Desktop\bitirmeVersion_8\Workout.Web\Assets\Videos" is the physical path to my videos and the url i used with localhost is "http://localhost:11124/Assets/Videos/video1.mp4"

Comment: 11124 port is also not blocked by my firewall